# EF6 создает новую не нужную запись

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

В этом месте объекту `truck` присваивается объект `trafficcolor`.

```
if (!CheckTruckAssigned(truck.TruckNumber) && !await CheckInactiveStatus(truck.TruckNumber))
{
    truck.TrafficColor = await _ratingService.GetTrafficColor(truck);
    context.Trucks.Add(truck);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Помимо создания нового объекта `truck`, `ef6` создает и новый объект `trafficcolor` я не пойму почему и зачем.
Вот метод `GetTrafficColor`, в нем создаётся отдельный контекст.

```
public async Task<TrafficColor> GetTrafficColor(Truck truck)
{
    try
    {
        TrafficColor color = null;

        var rating = await GetRatingCache(truck);

        if (rating == null)
        {
            rating = new RatingCache()
            {
                Score = 1,
                DepotCode = truck.DepotCode,
                TMSTruckTypeId = (int)truck.TruckTypeId
            };
        }

        //Рейтинг авто
        int score = await GetTruckRatingAsync(truck.TruckNumber);

        int constant = 100;

        int percent = (score * constant) / rating.Score;

        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var dev = context.DepotAndAKs.FirstOrDefault(dak => dak.DepotCode == truck.DepotCode);

            int trafficDeviation = dev.PercentDeviation + constant;

            if (percent > trafficDeviation)
            {
                color = context.TrafficColors.FirstOrDefault(tc => tc.Code == "Green" && tc.TMSTruckTypeId == truck.TruckTypeId);
            }
            else if (percent < trafficDeviation)
            {
                color = context.TrafficColors.FirstOrDefault(tc => tc.Code == "Red" && tc.TMSTruckTypeId == truck.TruckTypeId);
            }
            else
            {
                color = context.TrafficColors.FirstOrDefault(tc => tc.Code == "Yellow" && tc.TMSTruckTypeId == truck.TruckTypeId);
            }

        }

        return color;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex, Config.PathToServer, "Ошибка в GetTrafficColor - " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Контексты не шарят между собой элементы. Что пришло из бд для одного контекста будет новым классом для другого. Вам перед сохранением изменений надо выполнить что то типа `context.TrafficColors.Attach(trafficColor);`

Comment: @tym32167 пробовал, получаю парадоксальную ошибку - Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropria

Comment: Значит во втором контексте такая сущность уже есть в памяти. Тогда надо для обеих сущностей использовать один контекст, а не разные. Ну или может есть другие варианты, тут уже я не в курсе.